# How to solve c++ unwanted mathematical error

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ so what I like to do is make numerous calculators of anything, varying from area calculators to quadradic formula and etc. Anyways I'm creating a triangle area calculator but there is one small problem but first here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int triangle()
{
    int base;
    int height;
    int area;
    cout << "Enter base: ";
    cin >> base;
    cout << "Enter height: ";
    cin >> height;
    area = base * height /2;
    cout << area;
    return area;
}

int main ()
{
    cout << "Formula Calculator \n";
    cout << triangle();
    return 0;
}
```

The input is this:

```
Enter base: (I enter 4)
Enter height: (I enter 5)
1010
```

As you can see the 5 * 4  * 1/2 is not 10 for some reason every number that the area is, is always digit doubled if you know what I mean for ex if the area is 20 the program will show 2020, please help.

Answer (score 3):

You output the area twice.

```
cout << area; // here's once

cout << triangle(); // here's twice
```

I would suggest rethinking your code. Should the `triangle` function just compute the area or should it ask for input and do output? If the latter, why `cout << triangle();`?

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense, I'm new to programing especially to making my own functions, I just wanted the triangle function to compute the area and then the cout << triangle(); thing to output it.

Comment: Shawrtz one more question what if I wanted the program to say "The area of the triangle is (area)" without it repeating itself?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself, and always remember The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: "your computer will always do exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do". Keep that in mind, and you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

When you are inside your function `triangle()`, check it's 2nd last line, It is `cout<<area`, let's say you have given input `4` and `5` so inside the body of the function, at `cout<<area` it will output the area. Now it returns `area` which is then outputted by 2nd last line of your program i.e `cout<< traingle()//return value is outputted` so that's why we are seeing 2 outputs. It is not only in the case of `4` and `5`, but it will also output area `2` times in every case.